# Can't serialize a struct in an implemented method because "the trait `serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `Self`"

Tags: rust

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    pub field1: &'a str,
    pub field2: &'a str,
}

pub trait MyTrait {
    fn payload_to_json(&self) -> String {
        serde_json::to_string(&self)
    }
    fn do_the_thing(&self) {
        println!(payload_to_json(&self));
    }
}

impl MyTrait for MyStruct<'_> {}

fn main() {
    let n = MyStruct {
        field1: "foo"
        field2: "bar"
    }

    n.do_the_thing();
}
// What I'm hoping for: { "field1": "foo", "field2": "bar" }
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Self: Serialize` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:10:31
     |
10   |         serde_json::to_string(&self)
     |                               ^^^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `Self`
```

I'm new to Rust so probably missing something easy; the only struct implementing MyTrait does have `Serialize` implemented (unless I'm misunderstanding what derive() does), so I presume there's something that the compiler's not being told about .. somewhere. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your trait to `Serialize`:

```rust
pub trait MyTrait: Serialize {
    fn payload_to_json(&self) -> String {
        serde_json::to_string(&self).expect("A valid json")
    }
    fn do_the_thing(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.payload_to_json());
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a5a290369767430a351064e45b5598d4)